# Difference between iOS device and Simulator when loading XML content from URL

Tags: ios, xml, ios-simulator

The following code, receives and prints an XML from a given URL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString *xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", xmlString);
```

When the code executes on the simulator, one of the XML fields is:

```
<string><![CDATA[€ 45]]></string>
```

while, when the code is executed on an iOS device, the same XML field reads:

```
<string><![CDATA[45 €]]></string>
```

This however does not happen when there is dollar sign instead of a euro sign, when in both case the field is:

```
<string><![CDATA[$ 45]]></string>
```

Any ideas on why is this happening, or what can one do about it?

Any input is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The regional settings of your mobile device and development machine are not the same, that makes a difference for smart web-services.

From my experience some API added `Accept-Language` automatically and then the backend tried it's best to get the data from the localized database which failed as all the testing was conducted against English devices configuration. Adding the preferred language header manually instead of relying on the system configuration helped us to avoid such a problem.